# How to trigger a function when LinkButton in each row of the Grid is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` in which I have put an extra column **Details**, and in each row of the `GridView`, I have a `LinkButton` called Details. So when I click this I want an event to trigger.

The asp.net code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Details" runat="server" Text="Details"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use the [`LinkButton.Click-event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Details" OnClick="LinkClicked" runat="server" Text="Details">
```

in codebehind:

```
protected void LinkClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)link.NamingContainer; 
    // assuming there's a label with ID=Label1 in another TemplateField:
    Label label1 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");
    label1.Text="You clicked the link button";
}
```

If you need the `GridViewRow` of the `GridView` where the user clicked the link, for example to find controls in other `templateFields`, you can use the `NamingContainer`property.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: What cell data do you mean? Have you seen the `NamingContainer` part of my answer? If you're using `BoundFields` in the other columns with the "data" you need to use `row.Cells[cellIndex].Text` instead of `row.FindControl("controlID")`.

Answer (score 2):

Handle **GridView.RowCommand Event**

Occurs when a button is clicked in a GridView control.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Details"  commandname="Details" runat="server" Text="Details"></asp:LinkButton>


void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Details")
    {
     // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
     // property to an Integer.
     int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    //Your Code

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a command argument to determine which row was clicked (assuming you have more than one button (standard buttons/link buttons) in a row

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="GridViewOnItemCommand" runat="server">
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDetails" CommandName="Details" CommandArgument="YOUR_COMMAND_ARG_HERE" Text="Details" runat="server"/>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="YOUR_COMMAND_ARG_HERE" Text="Delete" runat="server"/>
    <ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

in the code behind file

```
protected void GridViewOnItemCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     //you can determine which button was clicked (detail or delete)
     var command = e.CommandName;

     //you can determine which row was clicked
     var arg = e.CommandArgument;

     if(command == "Details")
          ShowDetails(arg);
     if(command == "Delete")
          Delete(arg);
}
```

hope this helps